# How can I detect curves in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to detect all the curves in an image. I'm using python. I tried below code but it didn't detect all the curves in the image (red dotted circles). Can anybody please help to to know the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

from skimage import data, color
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

image = cv2.imread('s5.png',0)
edges = canny(image, sigma=6, low_threshold=35, high_threshold=50)

hough_radii = np.arange(20, 35, 2)
hough_res   = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)

accums, cx, cy, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, 
total_num_peaks=3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 4))
image   = color.gray2rgb(image)
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius)
    image[circy, circx] = (220, 20, 20)

ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image: output1]

[image: output2]

Comment: The Hough transform is for detecting circles, not for detecting generic curves. Is this your code?

Comment: This is the code I tried to run. Please do you know how can I detect generic curves?

Comment: By saying "curve" do you also mean prickly points and intersections? If yes, wouldn't edge detection algorithms are enough?

Comment: @H.Nagaty, why did you remove "How can I plot a circle on an existing image for the purpose of marking?"?

Comment: Are the red markings what your code did detect? Or what you wanted to detect? Please supply a second image showing what you wanted to find.